# Is possible to create dictionary with methods of class?

Tags: python, dictionary

Imagine, We have a class:

```
class Cat:
    def __init__ (self):
        pass
    
    def sayMeow (self):
        print('Meow!')


    def sayMrrr (self):
        print('Mrrrr!')


    def beHungry(self):
        print('Am am am am!')
```

and two (or more) objects of this class:

```
#...
    maria = Cat()
    adelina = Cat()
#...
```

We want to create a dictionary with methods of class, so that we would can call methods of `maria` and `adelina` from elements of this dictionary.

```
cat_methods = {
    'meow': 0, # TODO method sayMeow
    'mrrr': 0, # TODO method sayMrrr
    'am': 0 # TODO method beHungry
}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 5):

Sure – just put them there! [Methods accessed via class instances are bound to the instance](https://docs.python.org/3.10/tutorial/classes.html#method-objects), so you can just call them without extra hoops to jump through.

```
cat_methods = {
    'meow': maria.sayMeow,
    'mrrr': adelina.sayMrrr,
}

cat_methods["meow"]()
```

Your current `Cat` class can't express which cat is being vocal, but for show:

```
class Cat:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def sayMeow(self):
        print(f'{self.name}: Meow!')

    def sayMrrr(self):
        print(f'{self.name}: Mrrrr!')


maria = Cat("Maria")
adelina = Cat("Adelina")

cat_methods = {
    'meow': maria.sayMeow,
    'mrrr': adelina.sayMrrr,
}

cat_methods["meow"]()
cat_methods["mrrr"]()
```

prints out

```
Maria: Meow!
Adelina: Mrrrr!
```